# How to generate snippets in cucumber in javascript

Tags: javascript, cucumber

In visual studio code, I wrote the command in feature file but how to automatically generate the snippets in step definition file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you run cucumber it should propose you step definition for undefined step. Check tutorial https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/